# Opening an email in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, email

When holding down an email address in safari or mail client, a menu pops with the following options: new message, add to contacts, and copy. Is there a way to ad an option to this menu as a third party app that would open that app and insert that email address into it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `MFMailComposeViewController` in the MessageUI framework.